# Removing entire rows from a dataframe for which a specified column value contains null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Using python and pandas I am trying to remove entire rows from a dataframe where a value in a specific column is a null:
I have tried the following code using a for loop:

```
for row in dataframe.index:
    if pd.isnull(dataframe['Column'][i]):
        dataframe[.drop([i], axis=0, inplace=False)
```

However I got the following error:

> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

In your case, it would be like this:

```
dataframe.dropna(subset=['Column'], inplace=True, axis=0)
```